# getimagesize() not working on large images (640k+)

Tags: php, image-processing, gd

I am using PHPs GD extension for jpg image manipulation.

I am using `getimagesize()` to get image width and height.

It works fine locally as well as one one of my remote servers but not on another of my remote servers. The problem seems to arise on relatively large images (approximately 640k and larger). `getimagesize()` works fine for smaller images.

Has anyone come across a problem like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you need to increase PHP's memory limit, try doubling it initially to see if that fixes it. You can do so in your .htaccess (if you're using apache):

```
php_value memory_limit 16M
```

You can also set this in your scripts:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '16M');
```

Add this line into your script to see what error GD is giving you:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: Thank you sir! After an hour long debugging, it seems my server just didn't allow enough memory to process the image.  I set it to 128M on mine (8gb available) - is that something i should be concerned about? Only for one script that doesn't get used very often.